# Data on cultural diversity dimensions

Tags: data-request, research, demographics, global, social-process

I am looking for data on cultural differences across nations (regions), specifically:

- Power Distance
- Individualism vs collectivism
- Uncertainty avoidance
- Long-term orientation
- Personal Achievement (Masculinity vs Femininity)
- Loose vs Strict
- Universalism vs particularism
- Time Accuracy
- Directness vs indirectness